# Apple Configurator and DEP

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, dep

I have Several iPhone Some setup with Apple Configurator Manually and some setup with Apple Configurator and DEP.

Our Department requires that the phones we use are setup with DEP however the IT department isn’t too bright. What tests can do I do to figure out which of the devices are DEP enabled or not.

Second and do that end am I correct in saying that settings the Apple Configurator Manually can be undone by redoing the Apple Configurator Manually. Is that correct?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a double off-topic (phones and corporate IT policies/settings).

Comment: I think this would be on topic for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) but may require the complicity of your IT department. You can flag your own question to request migration there.

Comment: well im asking as an end user. not as an administrator.